# Processing image to get the accent color

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, bitmap, pixel

I want to get the most used color from image.

In most used color I dont mean specific pixel, I mean a most used color RANGE.

For example if there is an 2x3 pixels image and two pixels are f00(red) and the rest for are: 0b0, 0c0, 0d0, 0e0, 0f0 (Kind of green), I should get 0d0 (average of greens) and not the F00 (red, because there are exactly 2 pixels of this color).
I want to distinguish that kind of cases.
How am I supposed to do it? 
Or where can I find materials to learn how it can be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Search about **Color histogram** using matlab.

There are a lot of recourse for this topic.